# Can you access local static variables within local method in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, static, typescript

Lets say I have a class like below:

```
class Types
{
    static TypeOne = 1;
    static TypeTwo = 2;
    static TypeThree = 3;
    static TypeFour = 4;
    static TypeFive = 5;

    public GetNameFromType(type: number) : string
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case Types.TypeOne: return "TypeOne";
            case Types.TypeTwo: return "TypeTwo";
            case Types.TypeThree: return "TypeThree";
            case Types.TypeFour: return "TypeFour";
            case Types.TypeFive: return "TypeFive";
            default: return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Now after reading some documentation on static classes it seems like the above should work. however I keep getting an error saying that Types.TypeOne does not exist in the current scope.

So do I need to do anything else or should this just work?

== Edit ==

I didnt think it was outputting anything for it due to the errors, but it appears it has, here is the output:

```
var Types = (function () {
            function Types() { }
            Types.TypeOne = 1;
            Types.TypeTwo = 2;
            Types.TypeThree = 3;
            Types.TypeFour = 4;
            Types.TypeFive = 5;
            Types.TypeSix = 6;
            Types.prototype.GetNameFromType = function (type) {
                switch(type) {
                    case AbilityTypes.TypeOne:
                        return "TypeOne";
                    case AbilityTypes.TypeTwo:
                        return "TypeTwo";
                    case AbilityTypes.TypeThree:
                        return "TypeThree";
                    case AbilityTypes.TypeFour:
                        return "TypeFour";
                    case AbilityTypes.TypeFive:
                        return "TypeFive";
                    case AbilityTypes.TypeSix:
                        return "TypeSix";
                    default:
                        return "Unknown";
                }
            };
            return Types;
        })();
```

This looks legit, so maybe it is working and is just complaining...

Comment: It'd probably be elucidating to check what the generated code looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Typescript 0.8.3? Your code compiles fine for me. If the error is happening else where, try and define them as a 'public static'

Comment: AH ok will do that and yes 0.8.3 is the version im using. It is also within a module on my actual code, would that cause an issue?

Comment: Adding public still gave me the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Pasting that code into the Playground ( http://www.typescriptlang.org/playground ) shows no errors or warnings for me, and this is running the same 0.8.3 bits as the MSI.  I would uninstall/reinstall if you are seeing errors with just this code, as unless this is part of a larger project and the error is occurring elsewhere, then seems like something in the install must be out of whack.

Comment: I seem to be getting a few *strange* errors with my compiler. Will just assume that there is no issue and give the original answerer the tick.